# Fullcalendar closeon x before Title

Tags: css, fullcalendar

I´m using fullcalendar and I´ve got a question.

I´ve got the following function to delete an event from a day:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
            if(event.className != 'disableDelete'){ element.prepend( "<span class='closeon'>x</span>" );}
            element.find(".closeon").click(function() {
                 $j('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',event._id);
                 deleteDay(event);
            });
 },
```

Now, the Problem is, that the x is over the event-title, as shown [in this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeUt1.jpg)
But what I need is, that the x is on left side of the title.

Does Anybody find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply float your `<span>` to the left, and pad it a bit, with the following CSS rule:

```
.closeon
{
  float:left;
  padding:0 0.3em 0 0.3em;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/pd7hnLto/ for a demonstration

Comment: @AlexanderMenger no problem, please remember to accept (see the comment I just gave you on an earlier question).